# How can I create a vertical bootstrap responsive navigation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am pretty new at this. I would like to know how can I create a vertical navigation bar with bootstrap but I want it to be fixed in left side 100% height. And to be responsive for mobile. Here is an example of something I would like.

http://www.drawingart.org/

I have tried something like this but it's not really what I want

http://www.bootply.com/88026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to have a navigation column in your grid which become fixed at top left of the screen under a specific screen size (in this case xs and sm sizes). The main content should then take the whole screen width.

You just have to style the fixed navigation with CSS so it have a full height, negative left positioning (to hide it by default), different background color, etc.

Here is an example of the HTML "skeleton":

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 mobile-menu">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- your content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.mobile-menu {
  padding-top: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 240px;
    left: -243px;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 3px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Then you just need to add some Javascript to open/close the menu (actually a simple left:0 / left:-243px in this example), and maybe animations if you want.

I created something like this for Bootstrap you can find it [here](https://github.com/255kb/bs-mobilenav) and it is really easy to use.